# Scope of using namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces

After running the following code segment, the output is

> Outer.
>   Inner.
>   Inner.

I know this is about the usage of "namespace", but do not understand why the call of "Inner::message()" print out "Inner". Thanks for explanation.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
namespace Outer
{ 
    void message( );
    namespace Inner
    {  
        void  message( );
    }
}
int main( )
{ 
    Outer::message( );
    Outer::Inner::message( );

    using namespace Outer;
    Inner::message( );

    return 0;
}

namespace Outer
{   

    void message( )
    { 
        cout<< "Outer.\n";
    }
    namespace Inner
    { 
        void message( )
        {
            cout << "Inner.\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your formatting broke. Edit: You fixed your fomatting. Huzzah.

Comment: edited it, but it won't show until approved.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This makes perfect sense. Your are using namespace `Outer`. Inside of namespace `Outer` you have two members...

- `void message();`
- `void Inner::message();`

You explicitly scoped into `Inner` and called message there. Why would you expect otherwise? Had you not explicitly scoped into `Inner`, then it would have called `void Outer::message();`.

Answer (score 4):

What other function could `Inner::message()` possibly call?

Answer (score 0):

`Inner::message()` prints out "Inner". because of this

```
namespace Inner  
{   
    void message( )  
    {  
        cout << "Inner.\n";  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

They key is the line `using namespace Outer;` - this basically merges the namespace `Outer` with the global namespace, which means anything - even other namespaces *inside* that one - is now directly accessible from the global namespace, as if you were both in global *and* in the `Outer` namespace at once.

By the way: The only other alternative, if you assumed it would not print "Inner.", were for the code not to compile at all.